# how to do an on-change one-way sync/backup between folders on primary drive to secondary drive?

Tags: backup, cron, sync, rsync

I have two HDs in my machine. All of Ubuntu is installed on the main drive. The 2nd HD is empty and is for backup purposes. I want to configure a one-way sync/backup of /home/* to the 2nd HD.

I know I can use `rsync` and create a `cron` job but I am wondering if there is any way to do the sync/copy when files are changed in /home/*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) for this exact thing. It will watch a directory and sync changes over whenever files change, without needing `cron`.

[This page over at LiquidWeb](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-lsyncd-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) may help you get up and running. 
[This page over at Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-and-configure-lsyncd) may help too, but seems to require more manual labor.